# Quarkus with Vertx and RxJava2 imports yields NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x, reactivex, quarkus

I'm attempting to follow the basic examples on quarkus.io regarding using Vert.x. While attempting to use RxJava instead of the Axle API, I get a runtime error:

```
Error handling 24416339-00a4-4898-8373-b5d905b39179-2, org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.client.WebClient
```

My code for this class is as follows:

```
package io.blah.accountadminservice.client;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

//import io.vertx.axle.core.Vertx;
//import io.vertx.axle.ext.web.client.WebClient;

import io.vertx.reactivex.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.reactivex.ext.web.client.WebClient;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@ApplicationScoped
public class VaultClient {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VaultClient.class);

    @Inject
    Vertx vertx;

    private WebClient client;
    private String vaultToken;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "vault.host")
    private String vaultHost;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "vault.port")
    private String vaultPort;

    @ConfigProperty(name = "vault.loginPath")
    private String vaultLoginPath;

    @PostConstruct
    void initialize() {
        this.client = WebClient.create(vertx); // this kills it
    }

    public void getVaultToken() {
    }
}
```

When following the tutorial using the Axel API, I can build a web client. As soon switch to reactivex, these failures start happening.

My dependencies are:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>${mockito.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
      <version>${mockito.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-vertx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-rx-java2</artifactId>
      <version>${vertx-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

vertx-version is set to 3.7.1 at the moment. Side note: I've noticed when using the rxjava2 import, it's not possible to `import io.vertx.ext.web.client.WebClientOptions;` I don't know if that's supposed to work or not.

Comment: Can you post the dependencies you have in your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: Updated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you creating a fat-jar to execute. How are you executing? Basically this happens when you don't have the dependency at your runtime.

Comment: This is just running the quarkus dev maven task. I could add the shade plugin and try building the app. But I wouldn't think that should affect dev mode.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following dependency in your `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The version must match the version used in Quarkus.